# @Transactional not rolling back values

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, transactional

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how Java EE @Transactional works, I coded a simple example and it seems the the annotation doesn't work:

```
@Transactional(rollbackOn = BusinessException.class)
public void save() throws BusinessException {
    lista.add("Mary");
    validar();
    lista.add("John");
}
private void validar() throws BusinessException{
   throw new BusinessException("exception");
}
```

Even though the BusinessException happens, the value which was added to the list in the beginning of the method ("Mary") wasn't rolled back. Is that the expected behavior? Is @Transactional used only to manage database (and other resources) transaction?

Comment: @Transactional used only to manage **database transactions**.A transaction is a unit of work that is performed against a database. more basic info can be found here - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-transactions.htm

Comment: Thanks for the enlightment Sundararaj. I always thought the term transaction was more general here and the database transaction was also managed by @Transactional annotation.